# How to display only one AM and PM time in Full calendar js

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I know that time format issue has been already discussed. But stills i can't solve my problem.
My requirement looks like

[image]

Here I want to display all **AM** interval in a single **AM** and all **PM** time in a single **PM**.

Here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
    },

    defaultView: "agendaWeek",
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  });
```

});

Comment: You can't do that unfortunately. fullCalendar will always display a specific time of day (to be precise, the time at which the slot starts) in that location. You can control the format of that time, but it will always be a precise time, not a generic "AM" or "PM". But I suspect that it's ok in reality to do that, because I doubt your labs start at midnight really? I guess really they start at 9am or someting? And PM starts maybe at 12pm, or even maybe 1pm if it's after a lunch break? So it might actually be more informative to display that to your users...

Answer (score 0):

*replace format with this two line*

```
  timeFormat: "H:mm",
  slotLabelFormat: "HH:mm",
```

Comment: This is not according to  my requirement